# Static 4 digit passcode to access next html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, cordova

I have trawled google trying to find someone who has done what I am trying to do and cant seem to find anything, im thinking maybe im just not stating what I want in the right way.

Anyhow...

I have an IPad app created using PhoneGap and it is a simple offline form app, it consists of three html pages. What I would like to implement is to get from page 2 to 3 lets say, the user is required to enter a 4 digit code when they click the next page anchor tag button if they get the incorrect code all that happens is that it doesnt move to the next page, if they get it correct they continue to the next page, simple as that. There will be only one correct code, users dont sign up and have a username and password for example.

I am happy using html5, javascript, jquery.

Any ideas if this is possible and how I would go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know noting about iPad development or phonegap, but can't you just do:

```
<script>
    if(prompt("What is the number?") == "1234") { // Prompt for a number, check if its correct
        window.location.href = "/thenextpage.html"; // redirect them if it is
    }
</script>
```

Or:

```
<form name="myform" action="newpage.html"><input name="number"/></form>
<script>
    jQuery('[name=myform]').submit(
        function(evt) {
            // get the number from the form
            var numberVal = jQuery(evt.target).find('[name=number]').val();

            // Check the number's correct
            if(numberVal != "1234") {
                evt.preventDefault(); // Stop the form submitting
            }
        }
    );
</script>
```

Apologies if I've misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful and very simple :) Only problem is that preventDefault() did not work for me. I had to use return false to get pretty much the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using jQuery and adding an input text (or password).

```
var code = "1234";

$('a').click(function(e) {
    if($('input[type="text"]').val() != code) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful and very simple :) Only problem is that preventDefault() did not work for me. I had to use return false to get pretty much the same effect.